# Execute a shell script in release phase on Heroku

Tags: shell, heroku

I have two commands to execute in release phase and as per this tutorial (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase), I have included them in a shell script named *release.sh* (located in the root of my Django project).

```
#!/bin/bash

python manage.py migrate
python manage.py compress
```

In my *Procfile*, I added the script thus, as described in the article.

```
release: ./release.sh
web: gunicorn myapp.wsgi --log-file -
```

But during release I get the following error.

```
/bin/sh: 1: ./release.sh: not found
```

Then the release fails.

I don't know if the problem is with the path in *Procfile* (I also tried `bash $PWD/releash.sh`) or the file not being available at the time it is called. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

My *release.sh* was in a subfolder and that's why it wasn't found, but now I'm getting permission denied.

```
/bin/sh: 1: ./release.sh: Permission denied
```

Comment: Are you sure that the release.sh file is being pushed to the repository?

Comment: Oh my days! The file was in a sub-directory. And I spent hours trying one thing after the other. Thanks! A new problem has surfaced though. I'm getting `/bin/sh: 1: ./release.sh: Permission denied`.

Comment: Side Q: how many dynos is your program working with? _I'm getting an error on my app and I think it's because I'm using all my dynos up before execution?..._ @NicholasKajoh

Comment: @YaakovBressler I was using a single dyno.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This worked

```
chmod u+x release.sh && ./release.sh
```

So *Procfile* becomes

```
release: chmod u+x release.sh && ./release.sh
web: gunicorn myapp.wsgi --log-file -
```

Answer (score 13):

For this to work, `release.sh` must be executable

Locally, you could run `chmod a+x release.sh`. But you would not want to do that on heroku, so instead you can change the Profile to have this:

```
release: bash release.sh
web: gunicorn myapp.wsgi --log-file -
```

Comment: `bash release.sh` is the same thing as `./release.sh`

Comment: @NicholasKajoh `bash release.sh` doesn't care about whether `release.sh` is executable or not